# Not Found Apache/2.4.46 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1h PHP/7.4.12 Server at localhost Port 80

Tags: php, laravel

This are the env and composer.json file in the project folder I have given,

```
{
    "name": "devlpramit/gopotuappbackend",
    "version": "1.0",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "GoPotu APP Backend",
    "author": "Pramit Paul <pramitpaul1999@gmail.com>",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "intervention/image": "dev-master",
        "laravel/framework": "^6.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "symfony/error-handler": "^4.4",
        "symfony/mailer": "^4.3",
        "tymon/jwt-auth": "^1.0",
        "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "~9.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.5",
        "beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.0",
        "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^3.0",
        "phpunit/php-token-stream": "^3.1"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

```
APP_NAME="Laravel"
APP_ENV=development
APP_KEY=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8000/
# APP_URL=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=XXXXXXXXX
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

first there was a composer update error so I solved that by downloading php v  7.4.12,

AND I HAVE TRIED TO RUN THE PROJECT IN LOCAL HOST USING XAMMP THEN "php artisan serve"
IN localhost this error

Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.46 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1h PHP/7.4.12 Server at localhost Port 80

and in the terminal "php artisan serve" if use this then this error

[Fri Apr 14 19:39:38 2023] 127.0.0.1:52553 Closing
[Fri Apr 14 19:39:38 2023] 127.0.0.1:52554 Accepted
[Fri Apr 14 19:39:38 2023] 127.0.0.1:52554 Invalid request (Unsupported SSL request)
[Fri Apr 14 19:39:38 2023] 127.0.0.1:52554 Closing

Comment: Are you positively sure you're typing `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` in the browser? You seem to be invoking port 80 and/or HTTPS. Also, you installed Apache, are you sure you don't want to use it after all?